# Shortcut for mark variable shortly in ABAP editor (SE80)

Tags: ide, abap

As a .NET developer, I like the possibility of Visual Studio and many other editors, that a double-click on a variable would mark their entire name:

```
string name = "Test";
```

When I make a double-click on `name`, it is highlighted and I can apply useful operations like copying it. And Visual Studio also highlight all places in the code, where the variable is used.

Now I have to programm in ABAP using the advanced editor in `SE80`. Sadly, both features doesn't exist here. A double-click on a variable would open their type definition, which I was used to have on the F12 key in VS. Instead, the F12 key closes the mode, which caused a lot of errors in the beginning.

Is there a (short) way to get those features in the ABAP editor, too?

- Highlighting all usages of a variable
- Mark an entire string easily without selecting it manual using the mouse

Comment: Have you considered using eclipse as an IDE? I'll take eclipse over SE80 any day! You can download the plugin from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#abap and you just need some sicf services turned on in your SAP system to make it work! services that are needed are listed here: http://help.sap.com/download/netweaver/adt/sap_adt_configuration_guide_backend_en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For showing **all occurences of a variable**, position your cursor on the variable and click the yellow box with arrows on your toolbar or use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

[image]

I don't know another way for selecting the whole string except you can left click it while holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. If that doesn't mark the whole one, continue holding <kbd>shift</kbd> and click the beginning of it.

Comment: May also be worth noting that the `Where-used list` button has a hotkey: `Ctrl + Shift + F3`. Admittedly, it's a little lengthy...

Comment: @gkubed Thanks, I didn't even know that ^^

Answer (score 1):

Besides the where-used index (WUI) LPK already mentioned, you can highlight the variable name, hit Ctrl+F and then choose *Mark all*. This will place blue flags in the sidebar at every line that contains the variable name. Note that this is restricted to the current editor contents.

As for the shortcuts: F2 is statically assigned to the double-click, which in the ABAP environment is the drill-down navigation. F12 is statically assigned to the Abort function (the red of the three icons in the top. These assignments are used throughout the entire system and - mainly for consistency reasons - can not be changed by any developer. As far as I know, they existed for several years before Visual Studio was even invented, so they are almost certainly not going to change.

For better customization options, you might want to take a look at the ADT (ABAP in Eclipse) environment.